# Can I retrieve the actual line of code with stack trace?

Tags: c#, stack-trace

I have a quick-and-dirty unit test framework for my ASP.NET application -- an ASPX page with a method that compares expected and actual results and creates a table. It compiles as needed and lets me create and run a bevy of tests quickly, even without VS.NET running.

Here's an example call:

```
PrintResult(
   expected:  "$A$1", 
   actual:    RST.ExcelReference.FormatReferences("{{REF:1:0:1:0}}", false, 0, 0),
   arguments: "RST.ExcelReference.FormatReferences(\"{{REF:1:0:1:0}}\", false, 0, 0)");
```

(Named arguments added for clarity.)

As you can imagine, synchronizing the *actual* call and the *display* of that call is a pain.

I know I can't examine argument values in `Environment.StackTrace`, only the method definition and line number. But in my case, I don't need *actual* argument values. I'm generally calling this method using literals as arguments, so all I need is the line of source code for the entry point into PrintResult() in the Stack Trace.

The source code seems to be available to ASP.NET somehow, as it appears when there is an unhandled exception. How can I access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Environment.StackTrace` provides you with the file name and line number in each line of the stack trace.  It is clearly formatted and should be easily parseable.  From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace.aspx):

> The StackTrace property formats the stack trace information for each
>   method call as follows:
>
> "at FullClassName. MethodName (MethodParams) in FileName :line
>   LineNumber "
>
> The literal "at" is preceded by three spaces, and the literals "in"
>   and ":line" are omitted if debug symbols are not available. The
>   placeholders, FullClassName, MethodName, MethodParms, FileName, and
>   LineNumber, are replaced by actual values defined as follows:
>
> FullClassName The full name of the class, including the namespace.
>
> MethodName The name of the method.
>
> MethodParms The list of parameter type/name pairs. Each pair is
>   separated by a comma (","). This information is omitted if MethodName
>   takes zero parameters.
>
> FileName The name of the source file where the MethodName method is
>   declared. This information is omitted if debug symbols are not
>   available.
>
> LineNumber The number of the line in FileName that contains the source
>   code from MethodName for the instruction that is on the call stack.
>   This information is omitted if debug symbols are not available.

In the question you implied that `Environment.StackTrace` is not the answer to your question, but it seems like you should be able to parse out the source file name and line number, then go read that line from the file.  What am I missing?

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing so far... reading the ASPX's source code (Request.PhysicalPath) into a string list and printing the line for the frame's `GetFileLineNumber()-1`. Just seemed a bit weird to be reading the source code directly, thought there might be a more elegant way to do so. (I'm actually using `new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true)` rather than `Environment.StackTrace`, so there's no need to parse the string.)